# How can I extend a tornado template from a parent template by giving a path starting from template_path?

Tags: python, templates, tornado

I set the template_path configuration variable to the templates folder from my project.

In this folder I have the following templates:

```
base.html
admin/register.html
```

I want `register.html` to extend `base.html` so I have:

```
{% extend "base.html" %}
```

This results in the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/kj/Lab/test/templates/admin/base.html'
```

Apparently it's looking at the same directory with the child template.
Of course I can reach base.html with `../base.html` but I think it's much better if I can give it an "absolute path" (in the sense of starting from template_path)

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way `render` works, I don't think it's possible. When you pass the name of template to render function, like:

```
RequestHandler.render('admin/register.html')
```

`render` will start looking for the template from `template_path/admin` directory. `extends` which is an `operator`, searches the template in the `admin` directory, so you have to give relative path. I will update this answer if I find anything more.

**EDIT**: I have confirmed that this is not possible as of now and it has been added as an [feature request](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/731#issuecomment-58752885) on Tornado's issue tracker by Ben Darnell (he maintains Tornado project).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your information. Sad I have to wait. :)

Comment: as of today ( 2022 ) the request is still in `open` state :/ ... i'm moving to Mako Templates